# How to add stickers or labels for buy one get one offer in magento?

Tags: magento

Hi I need to create buy one get one free discount in shopping cart price rule..It is working fine but I want to have Stickers or Labels for the users to know the offer.How to do it??

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand what you're asking.

If you've made the rules in the CMS admin, then it's down to you to show on the front end how you want to visually display these offers isn't it?

You'll need to create the images, and then place them in your HTML markup

Comment: Thanks for your reply.I want the user to know this product has the offer..Where to place the HTML markup

Comment: From my memory of using Magento, which was a few years ago, in your Admin CMS you can either add it in the custom layout boxes when you edit a category, Or if you want it in a sidebar or on the homepage, then you'll need to edit one of the PHP files directly. If you right-click and Inspect Element on one of the boxes on the sidebar, find the class or ID in your PHP files, and look into making an override. Magento should have good documentation or user forums for editing content.